# Upgrading to the latest version of scipy

Tags: python, scipy, signals

I am trying to upgrade scipy.org's scipy python library from version 0.13.0b1 to version 0.19.0 (that contains signal.stft and signal.istft).  I followed the scipy installation instructions and re-installed it using 
Macports:

```
sudo port install py35-scipy
```

but when I check the scipy version I still have version 0.13.0b1.  Why is it not installing the latest version of scipy?

Comment: you can edit your post

Answer (score 0):

You can use pip to install and update scipy.

Try this to install pip:

```
python get-pip.py
```

Then upgrade:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then install scipy using pip:

```
pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose
```

Change the information as relevant to your system.

You can refer to the documentation here for more info: [Install SciPy](https://www.scipy.org/install.html)

Comment: I did exactly this, checked the scipy version and it is still '0.13.0b1'

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that /usr/bin/python was running python2.7, and for the new version of scipy to work it needs python3.6

FYI: if you are using Eclipse/PyDev you can change this in 
Preferences->PyDev->Interpreters->Python Interpreter